# How is this error estimate for the Jacobi method derived?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

If $x^{(*)}$ is the solution of a system of linear equations, the error bound for the Jacobi iteration is given by:
$$
||x^{(k)} - x^{(*)}||_\infty \leq \frac{\sigma^k}{1-\sigma}||x^{(1)}-x^{(0)}||_\infty
$$
I believe $\sigma$ denotes the spectral radius of our matrix, but I'm not sure how this formula is derived and also, we are assuming the iteration actually converges so that requires our matrix norm to be less than $1$ correct?

Answer (score 0):

The Jacobi iteration takes the form
$$x^{(k)} = \underbrace{D^{-1}b -D^{-1}(L+U) x^{(k-1)}}_{ = G(x^{(k)})}$$
So, the formula that you mention is just the standard a posteriori error formula from the fixed point theorem. Since you are using the $\infty$-norm, $\sigma = \|D^{-1}(L+U)\|_{\infty}$. If you were using the euclidean norm, it would be the spectral radius (of the same matrix).

For instance, if
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 1 & 0\\1 & 4 &1\\0 &1 &4\end{pmatrix}
$$

you have
$$
D^{-1}(L+U) = \begin{pmatrix}0 & \frac 14 & 0\\\frac 14 & 0 & \frac 14 \\ 0 &\frac 14 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$

and so,
$$
\sigma = \|D^{-1}(L+U)\|_{\infty} = \frac 12.
$$

This means that, in this case
$$
\|x^{(k)}-x^*\|_{\infty} \leq \frac{1}{2^{k-1}} \|x^{(1)}-x^{(0)}\|_{\infty}.
$$